# Whitelist http: content for Django application running SSL?

Tags: django, ssl, whitelist

In my Djanog web application I have added SSL security. Now In the django application I have integrated an external API which is running over http://.

This is the error i get after calling the external API.
[blocked] The page at 'https://mywebsite.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://api.external.com/moto.json?': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Can anyone help me out here on how should i whitelist the required external domains. And I am running the application on Apache server. So will this have to be done in Apache settings or Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is something that is being done at the browser as is not something you can control from your application or your web server.

Here is the [help article from Chome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714) that explains this behavior:

> Websites that ask for sensitive information, such as usernames and
>   passwords, often use secure connections to transmit content to and
>   from the computer you're using. If you're visiting a site via a secure
>   connection, Google Chrome will verify that the content on the webpage
>   has been transmitted safely. If it detects certain types of content on
>   the page coming from insecure channels, it can automatically prevent
>   the content from loading and you'll see a shield icon Insecure content
>   shield icon appearing in the address bar. By blocking the content and
>   possible security gaps, Chrome protects your information on the page
>   from falling into the wrong hands.

The only way to stop this from happening is to access the API over HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks Burhan for a quick response. That may be the reason why i couldn't find solution on web for this. I am trying with a django package https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers but not yet successful in whitelisting the http content for some domains.

Comment: CORS is not for this - besides, if CORS were the answer, it would need to be implemented by the API provider, not on your end.